# not able to use local variable outside the function after exporting

Tags: shell-script, variable

This is my script. Even after using the export command not able to use variable outside of the block. Below is the code that i have tried. i have tried other option like `declare -x var` but that is also not working. Can someone please please comment on this, am i doing right?

```
#!/bin/bash
{
    var="123"  
    export var   # exporting the variable so that i can access from anywhere   
    echo "var is "$var     # able to get the value of this variable
} | tee   log.txt

echo "var is "$var   # not able to get the value of this variable
```

Comment: still solution is not clear for me , so what the changes i have to done in code to access that variable . and thanks for ur reply and for ur valuable time .

Comment: The change you need to make is **DON'T set the variable in a pipeline** (except for the last segment in some non-bash shells and recent versions of bash with shopt lastpipe turned on, but you don't have it in the last segment anyway).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127334/bash-subshell-creation-with-curly-braces#answer-127346) accepted SOF answer:

> In a pipeline, all commands run concurrently (with their stdout/stdin connected by pipes) so in different processes.

So although the curly braces by themselves do not create a subshell, the pipe then does this (in bash); see e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
var=256

ps -u | grep $0
{
ps -u | grep $0
{
var="123"  
export var
echo "var is "$var

ps -u | grep $0

} | tee log.txt
echo "var is "$var
}

echo "var is "$var
```

So what we want is avoiding the pipe, while still having output on screen and to the logfile.
Luckily bash got the feature `<(...)` for creating temporary FIFOs. Example below shows a possibility where one still can use a code block, transfer its whole output to a log (here `stdout` and `stderr` are appended to different log files) and have the changed variables accessible later, as we do not get into a subshell.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

VAR=123
echo "VAR first: $VAR"

{
        VAR=256
        echo "VAR in block: $VAR"
        norealcommand
        # show open files to see FIFOs
        #lsof -p $$
        date
        otherbadcommand
}> >(tee -a stdout.log) 2> >(tee -a stderr.log >&2)

# dummy output to not mess up output order
echo | cat 

#lsof -p $$
echo "VAR after block: $VAR"

cat -n stdout.log 
cat -n stderr.log
```

which should result in something like this:

```
$ ./fifo                                                                            /dev/shm |myself@mydesk|0|12:04:10 
VAR first: 123
VAR in block: 256
./fifo: line 9: norealcommand: command not found
Mon Jul  3 12:04:37 CEST 2017
./fifo: line 13: otherbadcommand: command not found

VAR after block: 256
     1  VAR in block: 256
     2  Mon Jul  3 12:04:10 CEST 2017
     3  VAR in block: 256
     4  Mon Jul  3 12:04:37 CEST 2017
     1  ./fifo: line 9: norealcommand: command not found
     2  ./fifo: line 13: otherbadcommand: command not found
     3  ./fifo: line 9: norealcommand: command not found
     4  ./fifo: line 13: otherbadcommand: command not found
```

Hope this makes you happy :-)

Comment: awesome , thanks ! ,  thanks for ur valuable time , this solution is working .

Comment: how to get the value of var="123" , outside of curly braces .
I am getting output 123 , 256 ,256 .. but i want 123 123 123 .

Comment: maybe you'd like to accept as answer if ithelped :-)