# How to run subsequent commands after invoking a shell

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I have a script called `myscript.sh` with multiple commands within it

```
#!/bin/sh

singularity shell -B /home/user/Desktop/ /home/user/image/some_image.simg
/home/user/miniconda/activate my_env
cd /app/app_folder/scripts
ls -ash
```

The first command (line 3) invokes a shell and I want the subsequent commands to run within the invoked shell.

How do I get this to work properly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `singularity` shell, but Instead of an `sh` script, I'd write a `singularity` script.  I imagine you'd simply replace line 1 (shebang) with `#!/usr/bin/singularity shell -B ...` and remove line 3.

Comment: If `singularity` isn't a shell, and you actually trying to launch a few commands in an isolated shell, you can use a ["subshell"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93836/272848) using `( ... )` notation.

Comment: You'll probably get an error with that shebang line: remove the trailing slash -- `/bin/sh/` isn't a directory

Comment: thanks @glennjackman I have edited the question now. the trailing slash wasn't supposed to be there. typo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I had to replace `shell` with `exec` and save the subsequent commands in a different executable bash script `newscript.sh` which contains

```
#!/bin/sh

/home/user/miniconda/activate my_env
cd /app/app_folder/scripts
ls -ash
```

and then run `myscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

singularity exec -B /home/user/Desktop/ /home/user/image/some_image.simg bash newscript.sh
```

This method will run `newscript.sh` in the singularity shell after the singularity shell is invoked in `myscript.sh`

Answer (score 0):

With a glance at https://singularity.lbl.gov/archive/docs/v2-3/docs-shell looks like you want (untested):

```bsh
singularity shell -B /home/user/Desktop/ /home/user/image/some_image.simg -c '
  /home/user/miniconda/activate my_env
  cd /app/app_folder/scripts
  ls -ash
'
```

You may not be able to use newlines in the -c command, in which case try semicolons instead.